# PHP output buffering to text file

Tags: php, output-buffering

I am having trouble with an update script. It runs for a few hours so I would like it to output live to a text file.

I start the document with

```
ob_start();
```

Then within the while loop (as it iterates through the records of the database) I have this

```
$size=ob_get_length();
if ($size > 0)
{
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    logit($contents);
    ob_clean();
}
```

And finally the logit function

```
function logit($data)
{
    file_put_contents('log.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

However the log file remains empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the rights on the log file's path?

Comment: typing mistake. :) `$contents` => `$content`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
logit($content);
//           ^^ Note the missing s
```

Answer (score 0):

`$contents` is not the same variable as `$content`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here looking for a function for this, I wrote a nice one today:

```
//buffer php outout between consecutive calls and optionally store it to a file:
function buffer( $toFilePath=0, $appendToFile=0 ){
    $status = ob_get_status ();
    if($status['level']===1) return ob_start(); //start the buffer
    $res = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    if($toFilePath) file_put_contents($toFilePath, $res, ($appendToFile ? FILE_APPEND : null));
    return $res;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
buffer(); //start the buffer

echo(12345); //log some stuff
echo(678910);

$log = buffer('mylog.txt',1); //add these lines to a file (optional)

echo('Heres the latest log:'.$log);
```